# Info.plist is absent from left column (but present in FInder)

Tags: xcode, info.plist

I don't find my Info.plist. My project is running. If I go to finder, info.plist is present in the swift file list but doesn't appear in left column of xcode. Is it a problem ? It could be easier to access it from left column.

Comment: I think you should add your `Info.plist` manually because you need to set folder reference. You can simply drag and drop plist to left column of XCode.

Comment: Thank you @EmreCiftci just unckeck Target when I add file

Comment: if this answer works for you I'll write as an answer because of others benefits

Comment: Off course ! I tried to do it but I'm not the people who gave the good answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your `Info.plist` manually because you need to set folder reference.

***Simply ->***

- Open your `Info.plist` directory in Finder,
- Drag and drop your `Info.plist` to XCode's left column (Project Navigator)

I hope it will work for you.

Enjoy!